# import functions with the object using ES6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have an object defined as this

```
const apolloFetch = createApolloFetch();

function myFunction () {};

export default apolloFetch;
```

what I m trying to do is to import apolloFetch as this :

```
import apolloFetch from '***'
```

is it a manner to be able to access to the myFunction as the following :

```
apolloFetch.myFunction()
```

Comment: Uh, `myFunction` is not a property of the `appolloFetch` thing you created?

Comment: You really should use `export default const apolloFetch = …;` instead of `export default appolloFetch`. (Which changes nothing about your problem of course)

Comment: How are you going to use `apolloFetch` other than by calling `myFunction` on it? You might be looking for `import * as x from '***'; x.myFunction()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the `myFunction` to the `apolloFetch` object. It must be a property of the `apolloFetch` to be called like `apolloFetch.myFunction()`

```
const apolloFetch = createApolloFetch();

apolloFetch.myFunction = function() {};

export default apolloFetch;
```

Then you can do

```
import apolloFetch from '***'

apolloFetch.myFunction()
```

Comment: That's a pretty bad solution IMO - I'd rather avoid mutating the prototype and keep things clean exporting additional functions separately. If you have to do something like this then why not just add the function in the return object of `createApolloFetch`?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the **default and named exports** import approach following this example:

```
import defaultExport, { namedExport1, namedExport2 } from 'module';
```

So in your case it would be:

```
const apolloFetch = createApolloFetch();

export function myFunction () {};

export default apolloFetch;
```

Then while exporting:

```
import apolloFetch, { myFunction } from '***';
```

or

```
import * as apolloFetch from '***';
```

Comment: Thank you, but in fact in my case myFunction is using apolloFetch